# Questions about using Google API and Drive

Tags: android, api, location

I am currently attempting to use some Google Play Services in order to determine the user's exact location.

My current app utilises a Google Play Client to access the Google Play Services. However, I have a couple of issues surrounding this.

The Google Play Client uses a Drive API to contact the Google Play services. This is troublesome because that would mean I would need to compile the entire Google Drive API just for uses in 4 lines. In addition, I am not sure if I need the API key for it, in which case it would complicate matters even more.

So my question is:
**Is there an alternative to Google Play Client that does not include the addition of another API?**

and **I do need an API key for Google Drive API if I need to use it?**

The reason why I am compiling Google API selectively is because without selectively compiling, the GC limit is reached. However, this brought about a problem because now I can't import Connection Result, and so I can't tell if the connection failed or not.

**This there some other way to import Connection Result, or any way to replace it altogether?**

*Note*
If you wish to downvote a question, please provide an comment on why it is not a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you only using compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:X.X.X' in your gradle?

And yep you must generate an api-key at https://console.developers.google.com